# Rate limiting variable-duration operations over a time interval

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I want a rate-limiter that permits, at most, N operations over T seconds. I found a sample implementation [here](http://www.jackleitch.net/2010/10/better-rate-limiting-with-dot-net/) but it makes an assumption that operations complete in a predictable, consistent amount of time. I don't want to make that assumption.

My attempt to solve this simplifies the approach in the linked article by requiring the caller to signal when their operation completes. A timer fires every T seconds, releasing a SlimSemaphore the number of completed operations since the timer previously fired.

I'm looking for feedback on potential bugs, areas for improvement, and ways to make this more efficient.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

public class RateLimiter : IDisposable
{
    // Semaphore used to count and limit the number of occurrences per unit time.
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore;

    // Timer used to trigger exiting the semaphore.
    private readonly Timer batchTimer;

    // Whether this instance is disposed.
    private bool isDisposed;

    private int countCompleted;

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of occurrences allowed per unit of time.
    /// </summary>
    public int Occurrences { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The length of the time unit, in milliseconds.
    /// </summary>
    public int TimeUnitMilliseconds { get; private set; }

    public RateLimiter(int occurrences, TimeSpan timeUnit)
    {
        // Check the arguments.
        if (occurrences <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(occurrences), "Number of occurrences must be a positive integer");
        }

        if (timeUnit != timeUnit.Duration())
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeUnit), "Time unit must be a positive span of time");
        }

        if (timeUnit >= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(uint.MaxValue))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeUnit), "Time unit must be less than 2^32 milliseconds");
        }

        this.Occurrences = occurrences;
        this.TimeUnitMilliseconds = (int)timeUnit.TotalMilliseconds;
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.countCompleted, 0);

        // Create the semaphore, with the number of occurrences as the maximum count.
        this.semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(this.Occurrences, this.Occurrences);

        // Create a timer to exit the semaphore. Use the time unit as the original
        // interval length because that's the earliest we will need to exit the semaphore.
        this.batchTimer = new Timer(this.TimeUnitMilliseconds);
        this.batchTimer.Elapsed += this.OnBatchTimerElapsed;
        this.batchTimer.AutoReset = true;
        this.batchTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnBatchTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.semaphore.Release(Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.countCompleted, 0));
    }

    public void Completed()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref this.countCompleted);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks the current thread until allowed to proceed, or until the specified timeout elapses.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="millisecondsTimeout">Number of milliseconds to wait, or -1 to wait indefinitely.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the thread is allowed to proceed, or false if timed out</returns>
    public async Task<bool> WaitToProceed(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        // Check the arguments.
        if (millisecondsTimeout < -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("millisecondsTimeout");
        }

        this.CheckDisposed();

        // Block until we can enter the semaphore or until the timeout expires.
        return await this.semaphore.WaitAsync(millisecondsTimeout);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks the current thread indefinitely, until allowed to proceed.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<bool> WaitToProceed()
    {
        return await this.WaitToProceed(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    // Throws an ObjectDisposedException if this object is disposed.
    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (this.isDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("RateLimiter is already disposed");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases unmanaged resources held by an instance of this class.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases unmanaged resources held by an instance of this class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isDisposing">Whether this object is being disposed.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (this.isDisposed)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                // The semaphore and timer both implement IDisposable and 
                // therefore must be disposed.
                this.semaphore.Dispose();
                this.batchTimer.Dispose();

                this.isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

// Can process up to 40 operations per 10 seconds.
var rateLimiter = new RateLimiter(40, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await rateLimiter.WaitToProceed();
        // do stuff
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        rateLimiter.Completed();
    }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: One potential problem is that the user doesn't place the Completed function in a finally block. So if the // do stuff portion throws, a semaphore count is never released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO the use of `this.` before members in the methods reduces readability and is unnecessary.

---

`Occurrences` and `TimeUnitMilliseconds` should be immutable and only settable in the constructor so make it `private int Occurrences {get;}` or `private readonly int Occurrences`
     Alternatively you can make it public settable to allow for dynamic configuration?

---

> ```
> protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
> {
>   if (this.isDisposed)
>   {
>     if (isDisposing)
>     {
> ```

I think the `if (this.isDisposed)` should be `if (!isDisposed)`

---

> ```
>   if (timeUnit >= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(uint.MaxValue))
>   {
>     throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeUnit), "Time unit must be less than 2^32 milliseconds");
>   }
>   Occurrences = occurrences;
>   TimeUnitMilliseconds = (int)timeUnit.TotalMilliseconds;
> ```

Here you test `timeUnit` against `uint.MaxValue` and after that the value is cast to `int`. If `int.MaxValue < timeUnit < uint.MaxValue` the test is passed but the cast will result in a negative `TimeUnitMilliseconds`.

---

Your test case doesn't dispose the `RateLimiter` instance.

---

> `semaphore.Release(Interlocked.Exchange(ref countCompleted, 0));`

If `countCompleted == 0` this will fail. It can happen if no actions haven't terminated before the timer ticks.

---

> `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);`

This has no meaning if the class doesn't have a finalizer (`~RateLimiter()`) [GC.SuppressFinalize(Object) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=netframework-4.8)

---

A way to avoid that the users fail to call `Completed()` is to let `RateLimiter` handle the execution of the methods it self in a pattern like:

```
public class RateLimiter : IDisposable
{
  async public Task Run(Func<Task> func)
  {
    try
    {
      await WaitToProceed();
      await func();
    }
    finally
    {
      Completed();
    }
  }

  ....
}
```

And then make `WaitToProceed()` and `Completed()` as private members.

You'll of course need to provide serveral overloads of the above, that take a timeout value and/or cancellation token and/or have return values etc. And the class should maybe be renamed to something more suitable.

Comment: In your last point, if I use a Func, will exceptions thrown from func() bubble up to the caller of Run().

Comment: @Craig: Yes it will, but you can also catch exceptions inside Run() if you want to know about them there - and optionally rethrow them to be handled by the caller. All exceptions will be collected by the system and delivered to the caller in one `AggregateException`